# How to consume API in Redux application

Tags: reactjs, rest, react-redux, react-hooks

I have a CRUD application and, in addition to creating, editing and deleting posts, I also need to consume an API with some posts already created to render to the screen initially, but I don't know how to do this applied to my code(i'm using redux)... I have already created all the other features and will post the codes here, I would like to know how I could consume this API and what I would need to change in my code for this.

api: https://dev.codeleap.co.uk/careers/

postsslice.js:

```
   import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const fetchPosts = createAsyncThunk(
  "posts/fetchPosts",
  async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://dev.codeleap.co.uk/careers/");
      const data = await response.json();
      return data.results;
    } catch {
      
    }
  }
)

const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addPost (state, action) {
      state.push(action.payload); 
    },
  editPost(state, action) {
    const { id, title, content } = action.payload;
    const existingPost = state.find((post) => post.id === id);
    if (existingPost) {
      existingPost.title = title
      existingPost.content = content
    }
  },
  postDeleted(state, action) {
    const { id } = action.payload;
    const existingPost = state.some((post) => post.id === id);
    if (existingPost) {
    return state.filter((post) => post.id !== id);
    }
    },
    extraReducers: builder => {
      builder.addCase(fetchPosts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        return state.concat(action.payload);
      });
    },
},

});

export const { addPost, editPost, postDeleted } = postsSlice.actions

export default postsSlice
```

mainscreen.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "../_assets/App.css";
import "../_assets/mainscreen.css";
import { MdDeleteForever } from "react-icons/md";
import { FiEdit } from "react-icons/fi";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Signup from "./signup";
import Timestamp from "../components/Timestamp";

import BoxPost from "../components/boxPost.js";
import Modal from "../components/modal.jsx";
import EditModal from "../components/editmodal.jsx";

function MainScreen() {
  const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.loadPosts);

  const [openEditModal, setOpenEditModal] = useState();
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState();

  if (currentUser === "") {
    return <Signup />;
  } else {
    console.log({ posts });
    return (
      <div className="containerMainScreen">
        {openModal && <Modal deleteId={openModal} closeModal={setOpenModal} />}
        {openEditModal && (
          <EditModal editId={openEditModal} closeModal={setOpenEditModal} />
        )}
        <div className="bar">
          <h1>Codeleap</h1>
        </div>
        <BoxPost />
        {posts
          .slice()
          .reverse()
          .map((post) => (
            <div className="boxPost" key={post.id}>
              <div className="bar">
                <h1>{post.title}</h1>
                {currentUser === post.user ? (
                  <div className="bar">
                    <MdDeleteForever
                      className="icon"
                      onClick={() => {
                        setOpenModal(post.id);
                      }}
                    />
                    <FiEdit
                      onClick={() => {
                        setOpenEditModal(post.id);
                      }}
                      style={{
                        color: "white",
                        fontSize: "45px",
                        paddingLeft: "23px",
                      }}
                    />
                  </div>
                ) : null}
              </div>
              <div id="postowner">
                <div id="informations">
                  <h3>@{post.user}</h3>
                  <h3>
                    <Timestamp timestamp={post.date} />
                  </h3>
                </div>
                <br></br>
                <textarea
                  style={{ border: "none" }}
                  value={post.content}
                ></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default MainScreen;
```

store.js:

```
 import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
  import userSlice from './userslice';
  import postsSlice from './postsslice'

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        user: userSlice.reducer,
        loadPosts: postsSlice.reducer

    },
  })

  export default store
```

editmodal (modal to edit posts):

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import '../_assets/modaledit.css';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import {editPost} from '../redux/postsslice';

export function EditModal({ closeModal, editId}) {

    
    const post = useSelector((state) => state.loadPosts.find((post) => post.id === editId))
    const dispatch = useDispatch()



    const [title, setTitle] = useState(post?.title)
    const [content, setContent] = useState(post?.content)

    const [buttonGreyOut, setButtonGreyOut] = useState("#cccccc");

   useEffect(() => {
    if (title && content !== "") {
      setButtonGreyOut("black");
    } else {
      setButtonGreyOut("#cccccc");
    }
  },[title, content]);

    

    const onTitleChanged = e => setTitle(e.target.value)
    const onContentChanged = e => setContent(e.target.value)

    const onSavePostClicked = (e) => {
        
            e.preventDefault()
            dispatch(editPost({id: editId, title, content}))
            closeModal(false)
           
    }


    return (
        <div className="editmodalbackground">
            <div className="editmodalcontainer">
                <div className="title"><h1>Edit item</h1></div>
                <h2>Title</h2>
                <form>
                <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Hello World"
              name="name"
              value={title}
              onChange={onTitleChanged}
            ></input>
            <h2>Content</h2>
            <textarea
              placeholder="Content"
              name="content"
              value={content}
              onChange={onContentChanged}
            ></textarea>
                
                    <button onClick={onSavePostClicked} disabled={!title || !content} style={{backgroundColor: buttonGreyOut}}>SAVE</button></form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default EditModal
```

deleteModal:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../_assets/modal.css';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import { postDeleted } from '../redux/postsslice'


function Modal({ closeModal, deleteId }) {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const onSavePostClicked = (e) => {   
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch(postDeleted({id: deleteId}))
        closeModal(false)
       
}

    return (
        <div className="modalBackground">
            <div className="modalContainer">
                <div className="title"><h1>Are you sure you want to delete this item</h1></div>
                <div className="options">
                    <button onClick={() => closeModal(false)}>Cancel</button>
                    <button  onClick={onSavePostClicked}>OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Modal
```

Comment: I see. Well, you can use a mounting (*empty dependency array*) `useEffect` hook and make a GET request via `fetch` and then dispatch an action to store the response result into the posts state, or if you're a bit adventurous you could trying putting the asynchronous middleware included with RTK to work. If you are unfamiliar with Thunks/asynchronous actions then using the `useEffect` hook and dispatching an action is probably a little easier to grok.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, using a Thunk is also pretty trivial now in RTK.

Create a new asynchronous action (`createAsyncThunk`). This functions takes a string `type` and payload creator function arguments. Make the GET request to the endpoint and return the unpacked response value.

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const fetchPosts = createAsyncThunk(
  "posts/fetchPosts",
   async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://dev.codeleap.co.uk/careers/");
      const data = await response.json();
      return data.results;
    } catch {
      // if you want to handle any errors, failed fetches, etc...
    }
  }
);
```

and add a new reducer case in the `extraReducers` key of the posts slice. Here you'll use the fulfilled action type and return the current state with the fetched posts concatenated to the array from the reducer function.

```
const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    ... actions/reducers
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder.addCase(fetchPosts.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      return state.concat(action.payload);
    });
  },
});
```

App

You'll need to import the `fetchPosts` action and dispatch it when the component mounts.

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { fetchPosts } from "./redux/posts.slice";

...

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchPosts());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

MainScreen

This new data doesn't quite match the state shape you've established, namely it uses an `username` field property where you used `author`. The solution here is to switch over to using `username` in your `MainScreen` component. There's only two places to update.

1. When submitting a new post, use `username` now instead of `author.

   ```
   const handleSubmitSendPost = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     dispatch(
       addPost({
         id: uuidV4(),
         title,
         content,
         username: currentUser // <-- author to username
       })
     );
     setTitle("");
     setContent("");
   };
   ```
2. When mapping the data, it's `post.username` instead of `post.author`.

   ```
   <h3>@{post.username}</h3> // <-- post.author to post.username
   ```

[image: Edit cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-find (forked)]

Comment: I checked it on redux devtools and the data is being captured correctly, but I think the rendering didn't work, is there an error in my code or should I still implement the rendering of the captured data?

Comment: @HeitorKenzou Captured into the redux state correctly? But you're having an issue rendering it out? What are you experiencing? Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: the posts that are in the api are appearing in the redux devtools action, but the posts are not rendered on the screen

Comment: @HeitorKenzou They are certainly rendering out for me in the CSB I linked, 10 new posts. Is it working there, for you?

Comment: No... could you send me the sandbox link so I can check it with my code?

Comment: @HeitorKenzou Link is in answer, but here as well https://codesandbox.io/s/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-find-forked-4t2wr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=/src/redux/posts.slice.js&theme=dark&file=/src/redux/posts.slice.js:212-247

Comment: it works now! but something strange is happening, every time I go back to the create user page and back to posts, all posts are re-rendered (duplicate) and this happens infinitely, every time I go back to posts page they duplicate the API posts , is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @HeitorKenzou "(*though it is probably better to fetch this in App when the app mounts and renders so you don't refetch each time a user "logs" in and navigates to the main screen.*)" Move the dispatch to fetch into `App` should probably do the trick.

Comment: @HeitorKenzou I just updated my answer and linked CSB.

Comment: I'm very inattentive sorry!! it really worked now, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239225/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-heitor-kenzou).